# How can I swap elements in a valid sequence of a directed graph (e.g. swap jobs in a sequence of dependent jobs)

Tags: directed-graph

I have a directed graph of dependent jobs.

E.g. here job a has to be finished before job b, and a before c, before d.

```
   -> c -> d
  /
a -> b
```

Now given a valid job order (e.g. `[a,c,b,d]`) I want to swap two directly adjacent jobs (e.g. `b` and `c` to get `[a,b,c,d]`).

For any valid sequence of a given directed graph of jobs, is it sufficient to check if the left job (here `c`) is a direct predecessor of the right job (here `b`) in the graph (and if not swap them), to get a valid job sequence?

Is there a scientific proof for this?

Comment: To put it in other words, if you have a topological sort, will you arrive at a valid topological sort if you swap adjacent elements not constrained by the original partial ordering? The answer appears to be yes, mentioned in http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/24/1/83.full.pdf+html "when a transposition cannot take place". Not quite a proof, you can try going through the referenced papers if they treat this in any more detail. Or at least you have a new set of key words you can search for...